# Building varying levels of nested loops

Tags: ruby, loops, dynamic

I have an array to give a set of ranges like `range = [[10,15], [7,13], [2,3]..]`. I have nested iteration blocks using these ranges like below.

```
(10..15).each{|i|
  (7..13).each{|j|
    (2..3).each{|k|
        puts "#{k} - #{j} - #{i}"
      }
    }
 }
```

I have to form these nested loops dynamically based on size of the range array's size and their elements. I guess I should dynamically define a method by framing above iterations block and call the method to do the job. But I am not able to code this. Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`Array#product`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-product):

```
range = [[10, 15], [7, 13], [2, 3]]
range = range.map { |a,b| (a..b).to_a }
# range is now `[[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], [2, 3]]`
range[0].product(*range[1..-1]) { |xs|
  puts xs.join(' - ')
}
```

output:

```
10 - 7 - 2
10 - 7 - 3
10 - 8 - 2
...
15 - 12 - 3
15 - 13 - 2
15 - 13 - 3
```

---

**UPDATE** according to OP's comment. If you use older version of ruby that does not have `Array#product`, use following:

```
class Array
  def product(*others)
    if others.empty?
      each {|x| yield [x] }
    else
      each {|x| others[0].product(*others[1..-1]) { |ys| yield [x] + ys }}
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I didn't know about Array#product. Also i have not validated your answer, but you have taught me a lot of new things with this one answer. Thanks a lot! +1

Comment: @falsetru, I am using a older version of Ruby where Array.product is not available. In that case, how would I re-code this? please help.

Comment: @falsetru: can please help in extending Array class with product method?

Comment: @user2562153, Follow the link in the previous comment.

Comment: $falsetru: I am not able to find a code where I can add the product method to Array class. Can you give me the code please?

Comment: @user2562153, I updated the answer to include pure ruby version of `Array#product`.

Answer (score 0):

```
range = [[10,15], [7,13], [3,2]]
count = 0
str = ''
def dyn_levels(count, range)
    (range[count][0]..range[count][1]).each do |i|
        str.insert(str.size,i)
        if count < range.size
          str.insert(str.size,'-')
          count+=1
          dyn_level(count, range)
        end
    end
end
str.reverse!
```

Comment: It may not work, since you never decremented the `count` and also, this may not print the way OP requires it (actually let me rephrase, once you have moved to next array, you are not keeping the value from previous array).

Comment: thanks for pointing it out. I made some changes, i know its not optimal in anyways but i guess it might work now.